# Who composed the music for Red Baron II (Red Baron 3D), what are the names of the songs?

Tags: game-music-identification, red-baron-ii, red-baron-3d

I absolutely LOVE the shell music for Red Baron II (remastered as Red Baron 3D)--some of the best march music I ever heard. Unfortunately, I have no idea who wrote the music, or the names of the tracks.

The music can be heard [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lupk2oqy4JU). The YouTuber who posted the video also stated they did not know who wrote the music.

YouTuber [Rolf Orwar Strid](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4qlBWErAmszLuuhyUpsN5A) commented five years ago that the first track is from The Great Escape. However, in response, YouTuber [dixievfd55](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCOUCxSh0Dw9XbvMiPHxjoJA) clarified stating that it was the Hell's Angels patch that used the Great Escape theme. The theme can be heard [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MbsuAbTTsV8), but upon a close listen, they are in fact different despite the very close similarity (note the momentary pause [more like a hesitation] that recurs in the refrain, for instance). A relationship between the two may exist, but these are at least two different recordings, likely played by two different orchestras, and quite possibly written by different composers (marches do have a tendency to sound quite similar to one another).

*Additional note: if it were the case that the theme came from The Great Escape, this would still leave two of three tracks unaccounted for.*

Another YouTuber, [Halkalooki](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCzdVCrevkyjXujV1hRB5FhQ) , comments "I  posted  a while back on the simhq Red Baron forum asking if anyone knew who was playing this excellent music. I have the RB3D manual and they are not named in the game credits.". I was unable to find the aforementioned post or any relevant data on SimHQ.

I briefly looked over [PCGamingWiki's page](https://www.pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Red_Baron_3D) for Red Baron 3D, but did not find any relevant information.

MobyGames' page for the [Red Baron 3D credits](https://www.mobygames.com/game/windows/red-baron-3-d/credits) was fairly detailed, but made no mention of a composer or soundtracks.

Answer (score 3):

I vaguely remember playing this game at a friend's house when I was a youngster (Though I suspect it may have been Red Baron I), and it being exceedingly difficult. I've been doing some sleuthing regarding your question and have uncovered the following:

Red Baron II was released in December 1997. A patch was released in 1998 that added support for 3D acceleration and renamed the game to Red Baron 3D. (Source: Wikipedia).

A patch was released in August 24, 1998 that added support for 3D acceleration and renamed the game to Red Baron 3-D. It was soon released as a retail product a week later. (Source: Dynamix Wiki)

Sierra's Dynamix division... spent the last year working on a series of patches to bring the program up to speed and add 3D support. The result is Red Baron 3D, a program that's a worthy successor to the original...
Other than the fixes, the addition of 3D support, and multiplayer enhancements, Red Baron 3D is essentially the same program as last year's release. (Source: Amazon)

Red Baron 3D publications: https://www.sierrachest.com/index.php?a=games&id=332&title=red-baron-3d&fld=publications

So, to begin it bears mentioning that I could find no evidence that Red Baron II was completely reworked to the point that the musical score in Red Baron 3D was different. This is supported by numerous YouTube videos for Red Baron II music that is identical to the 3D version.

Exploring https://www.sierrachest.com/index.php?a=games&id=302&title=red-baron-2&fld=making&pid=100, within a site dedicated to parent company Sierra, I found that the music credits for Red Baron II are attributed to **Charles (Chuck) Barth**.

Similarly exploring https://dynamix.fandom.com/wiki/Red_Baron_II, a site dedicated to the developer of the Red Baron series. I found that the credit for music again goes to Charles (Chuck) Barth. Incidentally, and perhaps tellingly there is no mention of music credits in the Red Baron 3D page on the same site https://dynamix.fandom.com/wiki/Red_Baron_3-D.

Lastly a search for Charles Barth provides the LinkedIn profile for a gentleman who within the body of his work experience lists "Composer, Sound Designer" at "Sierra Games" during the period "1996 - 2002" which falls within the development period of Red Baron II/3D.

As for the names of the tracks, I cannot find any evidence of the tracks being giving names other than the section of the game to which they are associated, e.g. intro, outro (Please see: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL_BhbJAAueZTIQpV0LAmQN6lH9x1HoVNw and

) - this sometimes being the case in videogames.

Clearly the "shell" track, as you point out has been inspired by the "Great Escape" theme, however there is nothing conclusive about the titles or origins of each track (as far as I could find). The next step could possibly be contacting Mr. Barth himself and seeing if he could provide more details regarding his work on the Red Baron II/3D score.

Finally I discovered this old thread within the SimHQ forums, which may be the one you mention, that reinforces some of my findings: https://simhq.com/forum/ubbthreads.php/topics/3182079/red-baron-ii-music

I hope this goes some way in shedding more light on the matter.